# С помощью каких инструментов можно одинаково подготовить 6 ПК?

Tags: linux, ansible, devops

Есть 6 ПК без ОС. На всех них нужно установить Ubuntu, java, postgreSQL и одно приложение(установка выглядит как запуск скрипта в терминале). Так же прописать статичные IP адреса. Везде все ПО и настройки абсолютно идентичны.

С помощью каких инструментов, если такие существуют, я могу упростить себе жизнь и не устанавливать и настраивать каждую машину вручную, а сделать это с помощью какого-либо инструмента\технологии?

Есть уже 1 готовый ПК, который выполняет свои задачи. Могу ли я использовать его в качестве точки для управления точно такими же шестью? И собственно как-то его использовать для ускорения настройки других шести?
Все 7 ПК по итогу будут территориально удалены друг от друга и увы с динамичными IP. Только 1 из них с статичным. Вопрос о приобретении белых адресов еще рассматривается.

Почитал про Ансибл. Я так понимаю всей моей задачи он не решает. То есть конфигурировать сможет только уже установленную ОС. А еще момент с установкой массовой надо решить.
CloneZilla рассмотрел, но на перспективу освоить новые и нужные технологии не подходит.

Comment: Снять образ настроенного ПК Акронисом и разлить на остальные ПК, после этого для поддержки установить ansible

Comment: Я смогу им что-то сделать потом на удаленных от меня машинах учитывая топологию сети, которую я расписал? Без белых IP?

Comment: Снятие образа продублирует все ssh-ключи и прочие уникальные для конкретной машины идентификаторы, поэтому я считаю это не очень хорошей идеей

Comment: [How to install Linux on multiple PCs at once?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/596030/110559), ну а потом уже применить любую удобную систему автоматической настройки: saltstack, ansible, puppet, chef, и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Подразобрался в мат.части, аккумулировал советы:

Установка ОСи: Кикстарт, pxe, Cobbler.

Конфигурирование: Ansible.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).